# Javascript: Tracing a Function Parent Object Hierarchy, In Order to Call It From the Window Context

Tags: javascript

I have a 3rd-party page with a complex, semi-obfuscated script generated by WebPack. 
It eventually calls a function, buried deep inside some object within an object within an array, etc. When debugging it I can see the line where the function is called at, but I want to trace the entire object hierarchy so I can call this function from the window context.

When debugging and breakpointing the relevant line, I get the call stack, but this doesn't help me reverse-engineer the way I can call this function, since it's buried within objects and arrays.

Is there any way to trace this backwards? For example, maybe have the Function object print its parents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this "Get the stack trace for a function" in the following article 
[Javascript Tips & Tricks you didn't know](https://raygun.io/blog/2015/06/useful-javascript-debugging-tips-you-didnt-know/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Link sadly turned into a 404.